# setState function not updating image under stateful widget

Tags: flutter

*I was trying to build Dice Game in which if users click the image should be changed from the asset folder but the image is not changing but the value in the terminal is updating setState Method is not working properly maybe*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Dicee')),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int leftDiceNumber = 5;
    int rightDiceNumber = 2;
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  print('$leftDiceNumber');
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  rightDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  print('$rightDiceNumber');
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**it should show the updated images**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your variables outside of the build method. They are being reset on each build.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  return runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Dicee')),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
        body: DicePage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
class DicePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DicePageState createState() => _DicePageState();
}

class _DicePageState extends State<DicePage> {
  int leftDiceNumber = 5;
  int rightDiceNumber = 2;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  leftDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  print('$leftDiceNumber');
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$leftDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  rightDiceNumber = Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
                  print('$rightDiceNumber');
                });
              },
              child: Image.asset('images/dice$rightDiceNumber.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```